# iOS - two App targets, shared in-app purchases

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, icloud

If I have a both an iPhone and iPad version of an app, can they share in-app purchases? If a user makes a purchase on their iPhone, then downloads the app on an iPad, I need the app to respect the purchase.

I have a lot of artwork files so the app is fairly large, and I'm wondering if separate apps are the way to go in this case, instead of a universal app.

So it is possible to share in-app purchases with two different targets? I have read a few things that mention iCloud in this scenario, but have no idea how that would work.

Answer (score 1):

No. In-app purchase products are associated with apps bundle IDs. You'd need to go with an universal app.